# YoutubePlayerView in Fragment

Tags: android, youtube, orientation, fragment

I have a flexible UI layout. One fragment in handheld devices and 2 fragments in a tablet. In the Details Fragment, this will contain a youtube video and some other views. I am using Youtube API to do this.

I have tried using YoutubePlayerSupportFragment defined in the xml file and it works fine on first load. But when going back to the List view and then reopening the details view, I get a duplicate ID error. This is because the onCreateView for the DetailsFragment is loading the layout again.

I tried to replace this with FrameLayout and dynamically add the YoutubeFragment which solved the problem above. However, when changing orientation, it reloads the entire fragment and the youtube video is restarted from the beginning.

What I want is to have the youtube video inside the fragment and handle screen changes (like orientation or fullscreen mode) without the video rebuffering. There was a sample app provided in android developer page to accomplish this but they are using YoutubePlayerView in the XML file which requires the container to be an activity inheriting from YoutubeBaseActivity which doesn't work in my situation since I'm using a Fragment. What is the proper way of implementing this?

DetailFragment.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView .. />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <Button ... />

</LinearLayout>
```

DetailFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.DetailFragment, container, false);
        ...

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.youtube_fragment);
        youTubeView.initialize(Utilities.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.. replacing with framelayout helped for my requirement..